# Prevent flicker while loading QQuickView

Tags: qt, qt5, qwidget, qquickview

I have a `QStackedLayout` with two `QWidget` objects added to it. Second `QWidget` is created like this:

```
QQuickView *view = new QQuickView();
view->setColor(Qt::transparent);
view->setSource(QUrl("qrc:/main.qml"));
m_qmlWidget = QWidget::createWindowContainer(view, this); // this is a QWidget object
```

Now I want to be able to show and hide the second (top) widget. I do this by calling `m_qmlWidget->setVisible(false);` or `m_qmlWidget->setVisible(true);` but whenever I do this the widget is being painted whole blank (white color) and shortly after it changes background to transparent color. This is a problem to me because first widget will be mostly black. I think the reason of the problem is that QML file is being loaded and it blocks repaint event. Two solutions that come to my mind are:

- load QML file asynchronously
- do not unload the second widget when it is not visible

I am afraid that both of those options are impossible to do. How can I solve the problem with flickering white background?

The flicker happens when I change `visible` of the second `QWidget` to true or false. I do not understand why the flicker happens on hiding the top widget.

---

[Here](https://github.com/fhazubski/QQuickViewFlickerProblem) you can find a working example project. Maybe the `QOpenGLWidget` object is the problem here. Creating two widgets did not seem to produce the problem.

Comment: Paste more code to be more illustrative.

Comment: @CoolGuyCG It would be too much files to paste so I have created example project and added it to the question.